# What do I need to do to get 100% completion?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I have pretty much done everything there is to do in the game that is listed as quests and other unlisted tasks. I'm currently at 98.43% completion... but I don't know what else I can do to increase that number further. It seems like anything else I do doesn't bump up the completion. I'm currently on a mission to kill every boss-type enemy in the world to get the medals.

[image]
*map of the surface*

[image]
*page 1 of key items*

[image]
*page 2 of key items*

I've been following this checklist and there are some items I have not listed here. (champion's leathers fabric)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y1fQi-U63_Arl8HDFWNnVCu9fye8eWFhLfQ8bd1JpY4/edit?usp=sharing

- I defeated the final boss(es)
- I have completed all listed main/side/shrine quests and side adventures
- I have all 1000 korok seeds
- I have found and completed all shrines and lightroots
- I have all weapons and armors
- I have all sages upgraded
- I have all schema stones (12), yiga schematics (34), old maps (31)
- I have the full hyrule compendium
- I've completed various unmarked tasks (from what I can remember):

  - helped the gerudo night school
  - helped the gerudo with the message bottles
  - helped other random characters with tasks

All I'm missing as far as I can tell:

- Not all armors are fully upgraded
- Not all horses are fully upgraded
- Not all enemy medals have been collected (so far, only molduga medal)
- A lot of fabrics still missing

Are there some things that do not contribute to the progression? Which ones *must* I do to get to 100%? Do I really have to get all medals, fabrics, and armor and horses upgraded?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I got 100% on BotW by doing everything listed as well as getting all koroks and that was it. What else is left here?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like what I'm specifically missing is revealing locations that are named on the map. I tried going doing different tasks and apparently there are some places in the depths I have not visited, despite being revealed on the map. I'll have to review my hero's path and compare with the full maps and find what I can. At least with this knowledge, I was able to increase my percentage. Hopefully this will be all that's left.

**So if you're hoping to 100% (according to the game), you'll want to make sure you're visiting every settlement, bridge, ruins, mine, etc. you can find.**

I think I've reached the end of my rope with this and lost the will to complete. I'm sitting at about 99.75% and went through just about every spot on a complete map and could not find any more undiscovered locations. Also went through all bosses I could find to get the medals and missed a handful of them... but I don't think they even contribute to the completion.

I'd try to upgrade the rest of my remaining armors but the time needed to gather the materials necessary (waiting for at least 2 more blood moons), considering how little I find these in the world. I'm not going to even bother further with the horses. And I got all the fabrics I can get without Amiibo.

Fought the last battle again and it didn't make a difference. There's technically unlisted locations there but they don't stay on the map.

Comment: I missed at least one location on Botw too, so annoying...

Comment: Fortunately it's not too difficult to see what places are not discovered. If you don't see a name on the map, and it's named on a complete map, then you'll know to go there. You don't need to be super zoomed in either like with the Koroks and at least have some indicator (unlike with Addison the sign guy).

Comment: Found two more bridges, now at 99.71%... So 0.06% per location, meaning potentially 4 more locations and another 0.05% leftover.

Comment: I feel you, the struggle is real.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you must find every named location, with each one adding ~0.04% to your *map* completion rate, which is the thing you are currently attempting to maximize. Every shrine, Skyview Tower, Korok, named bridge, depths mine, chasm, lightroot, well, grove, forest, cave entrance, and anything else with a name that shows up on the map is required for 100% map completion. The "trophy" key items are separate from this, as they are awarded for other things, and don't add anything to this percentage. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvL0YnIjyCU) for more information.